# Workflow fails with no explanation because I assign a variable

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following workflow step:

```
    -   name: Set IMAGE_EXISTS, UMBRELLA_SHA
        id: set_image_exists
        working-directory: umbrella
        run: |
            echo $(docker images --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}|{{.CreatedAt}}" | grep "full_node:*" | egrep "$(printf "$(for i in {1..30}; do echo $i' day ago'; done)" | date +'%Y-%m-%d' -f - | sed -z 's/\n/|/g' | sed 's/.$//' )" | awk -F'|' '{print$1}' | sort -u | xargs)
            echo GOT_A
            OLD_IMAGES=$(docker images --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}|{{.CreatedAt}}" | grep "full_node:*" | egrep "$(printf "$(for i in {1..30}; do echo $i' day ago'; done)" | date +'%Y-%m-%d' -f - | sed -z 's/\n/|/g' | sed 's/.$//' )" | awk -F'|' '{print$1}' | sort -u | xargs)
            echo GOT_B
        shell: bash
```

Github action doesn't show any error output at all. It prints "GOT_A", then fails on the next line... even though the line that follows it is identical to the echo line just above it.

After pulling my hair out, looking at debug logs which just says

```
2023-10-11T01:12:31.1321162Z GOT_A
2023-10-11T01:12:31.1841437Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I finally tried wrapping the assignment with an extraneous echo...:

`OLD_IMAGES=$(echo $(docker images --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}|{{.CreatedAt}}" | grep "full_node:*" | egrep "$(printf "$(for i in {1..30}; do echo $i' day ago'; done)" | date +'%Y-%m-%d' -f - | sed -z 's/\n/|/g' | sed 's/.$//' )" | awk -F'|' '{print$1}' | sort -u | xargs) )`

magically, everything works. This isn't required locally... why does GitHub Actions require this? Why aren't I getting an actual error message?

Comment: Can you please try without `shell: bash`? With `shell: bash`, `-o pipefail` is also added in the [shell invocation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell). I suspect that some command(s) in your pipeline fails which causes this i.e. non-zero exit code. Prefixing it with `echo` indirectly suppresses it which may not be your intention. Apart from that, you might want to lint your Bash script with https://www.shellcheck.net/. There might be issues that you'd want to fix.